# Object being replaced instead of updating in Realm Objective C

Tags: objective-c, realm

I have an object from a backend as such

`dummyObj{ name, number, image and id }`

I have added on my RLMObject model another bool attribute called `isFav`. I have called the method `primaryKey` on my model and set `id` as the primary key.

The problem is every time I update my objects, the `isFav` property is replaced to 0 and it's old value does not remain the same.

I have actually used this scenario before in another app and it worked fine with the only exception I was using an older realm version.

Currently the exact methods I'm using are:

```
  DummyObj *testObj = [DummyObj mj_objectWithKeyValues:jsonDic];
 [DummyObj createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithValue:testObj];
```

the `mj_objectWithKeyValues` is the MJExtension library for json-model mapping.

I also tried `[realm addOrUpdateObject: testObj];`

I had implemented also the method `defaultPropertyValues` on my model and set a default value for the `isFav` property and later I removed it all together and still the object is being replaced instead of updated for the same id.

and from the documentation

> Please note that when updating objects, `NSNull` is still considered a valid value for optional properties. If you supply a dictionary with `NSNull` property values, then these will be applied to your object and those properties will be emptied. To ensure you don’t experience any unplanned data loss, please make sure to provide only the properties you wish to update when using this method.

but actually I'm only supplying the properties that I wish to update, yet it updates the `isFav` property.

The exact class for dummyObj is

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Realm/Realm.h>
#import "Tags.h"
#import "BusinessCategory.h"
#import <MJExtension/MJExtension.h>


RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Tags)
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(BusinessCategory)

@interface HotlineNumber : RLMObject

@property NSString *hotlineName;
@property NSString *hotlineNumber;
@property NSString *hotlineImage;
@property NSInteger hotlineID;
@property BOOL isFav;

@property RLMArray<BusinessCategory> *categories;
@property RLMArray<Tags> *hotlineTags;

@end
```

and my implementation file is:

```
#import "HotlineNumber.h"

@implementation HotlineNumber

//
//+ (NSDictionary *) defaultPropertyValues{
//    
//    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
//    dict[@"isFav"] = @NO;
//    
//    return dict;
//}

+ (NSString *) primaryKey {
    return @"hotlineID";
}

+ (NSDictionary *) mj_objectClassInArray{

    return @{
             @"categories" : @"BusinessCategory",
             @"hotlineTags": @"Tags"
             };
}

@end
```

and my jsonDict is as follows
`{
"hotlineID": 241,
"hotlineName": "Abaza Auto Trade",
"hotlineNumber": "16876",
"hotlineImage": "",
     "categories": [
       {
       "catId": 92,
       "catName": "Automotive",
       "catIcon": "",
       "catColor": "#03a9f4",
       "catOrder": "",
       "isParent": "false"
       }
      ],
"hotlineTags": [ ]
}`

Comment: Can you please share the declaration of your `DummyObj` class, and the exact contents of `jsonDic` that you're passing to `+ mj_objectWithKeyValues:`?

Comment: @bdash I have added the exact contents. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that partial updates of an object cannot be performed by passing an instance of an `RLMObject` subclass to `+createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithValue:`. The reason for this is that there's no way to represent *don't update this property* for a property on your `RLMObject` subclass. You'll instead want to pass a dictionary to `+ createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithValue:`, where the absence of a given key represents *don't update this property*.

To expand on this further, your code that performs the updating is:

```
DummyObj *testObj = [DummyObj mj_objectWithKeyValues:jsonDic];
[DummyObj createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithValue:testObj];
```

This asks that the existing object with the same primary key value as `testObj` be updated so that all of its properties have the same values as `testObj`. `testObj`'s `isFav` property is equal to `NO`, so the existing object is updated to have `isFav = NO`.

So why does `testObj.isFav == NO`? Because `+mj_objectWithKeyValues:` returns an instance of `DummyObj`, and `DummyObj`'s `isFav` property must have a value. If `isFav` is present in the dictionary you pass to `+mj_objectWithKeyValues:`, the instance it returns will have that value. If a value is not present in the dictionary, as is the case for `isFav` in the sample data you provided, the instance variable will be not be explicitly initialized and will remain at its default-allocated state (e.g., zero).

Comment: Thanks a lot @bdash. I can't believe I fell for such a mistake and even thou in beginning I was passing the dictionary and then somehow in the process I changed it to the above. Thanks again. :)